# How to reference this in closure

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, routes, closures

I am using PHP Version 7.1.1.

In `index.php` of my MVC I create a route collection (`$routes`). To it I want to add a route group (with `addGroup`). This addition process relies on a closure (e.g. an anonymous function), passed as argument to `addGroup`. Inside of closure **I am trying to reference the collection with `$this`**, so that I can add one or more routes to it (with `addRoute`, a method of the collection).

Unfortunately I could not achieve that, although I made some tries. I miss a piece of the closures theory, somewhere. I would appreciate, if you would provide me an advice.

The "problem" is, that, in order to achieve a simplified usability for the user, I am trying to avoid the direct use of a closure parameter. Why? Because inside `addGroup` I am already in the collection's scope and from there I am calling the closure. This way I can pass the collection's instance (`$this`) as argument to the `executeGroupHandler` method and, therefore to `executeGroupHandler` as well.

Thank you for your time and patience!

---

#### index.php

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->addGroup('/test', function() {
    $this->addRoute('GET', '/group', function() {
        echo 'Hello from route /test/group';
    });
});
```

#### RouteCollection

```
class RouteCollection implements CollectionInterface {

    public function addGroup(string $groupPattern, callable $groupHandler) {
        $group = new RouteGroup($groupPattern, $groupHandler);

        return $group->executeGroupHandler($this);
    }

    public function addRoute($httpMethod, string $routePattern, $routeHandler) {
        //...
        return $this;
    }

}
```

#### RouteGroup

```
class RouteGroup {

    private $groupPattern;
    private $groupHandler;

    public function __construct(string $groupPattern, callable $groupHandler) {
        $this->groupPattern = $groupPattern;
        $this->groupHandler = $groupHandler;
    }

    public function executeGroupHandler(CollectionInterface $routeCollection) {
        return call_user_func_array($this->groupHandler, [$routeCollection]);
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your question, Phoenix. Important, indeed. I reedited my question. It is PHP 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to present the solution in this post, as accepted answer, only to provide a compact overview of it, together with its implementation. But:

### Credits:

The solution that elegantly fulfills all my requirements, and that I have chosen to use, was kindly presented by @apokryfos. The idea proposed by @ArtisticPhoenix was very correct as well.

Thank you very much guys! I appreciate your help.

### Solution:

**The idea is, that, if you bind the closure to an object - in my case the collection (`$routes`), then the object is accessible within the scope of the closure and can be referenced with `$this`.**

Based on this idea I could achieve an implementation which not only allows the user to not pass any arguments to the group handler callback (the closure function), but also to still pass arguments (the container object `$routes`) if he wishes it.

### Implementation of the solution:

#### index.php

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes
    // The most simple and elegant use-case.
    ->addGroup('/group1', function() {
        $this->addRoute('GET', '/route1', function() {
            echo 'Hello from route /group1/route1';
        });
    })
    // An optional use-case.
    ->addGroup('/group2', function($routes) {
        $routes->addRoute('GET', '/route1', function() {
            echo 'Hello from route /group2/route1';
        });
    })
    // Another optional use-case.
    ->addGroup('/group3', function() use ($routes) {
        $routes->addRoute('GET', '/route1', function() {
            echo 'Hello from route /group3/route1';
        });
    })
;
```

#### RouteCollection

```
class RouteCollection implements CollectionInterface {

    public function addGroup(string $groupPattern, callable $groupHandler) {
        if ($groupHandler instanceof Closure) {
            $groupHandler = $groupHandler->bindTo($this);
        }

        $group = new RouteGroup($groupPattern, $groupHandler);

        $group->executeGroupHandler($this);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

#### RouteGroup

```
class RouteGroup {

    public function executeGroupHandler(CollectionInterface $routeCollection) {
        return call_user_func_array($this->groupHandler, [$routeCollection]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$routes->addGroup('/test', function() use ($routes) {
    $routes->addRoute('GET', '/group', function() {
        echo 'Hello from route /test/group';
    });
});
```

You are trying to access `$this` or `$routes` from a closure that is outside the scope of the class

Comment: The thing is, that I am trying to avoid the direct use of a closure parameter. Why? Because inside `addGroup` I am already in the collection and from there I am calling the closure. I know that it may be impossible without defining a closure parameter. But I just hope that there can be another way.

Comment: If you can further explain what you mean by not using a closure parameter that would help? As far as I know a closure is what PHP calls an anonymous functions.

Comment: Please don't take me wrong: I definitely take in consideration your solution proposal! As for your question, I don't have a lot of experience with closures, but I will try to explain in my words. For this, I have to debug my project a little bit, so that I can find out what I am trying to do without params and how to explain it. Just give me a little time.

Comment: Well, it's something like this: When the closure is called with `call_user_func_array` in `RouteCollection::executeGroupHandler`, then the container object is available (defined as `$parent`) and passed as argument to the `call_user_func_array` function. In my vision, there is hopefully a magic thing in closures, that allows me to access the passed argument (the collection's instance) inside the closure, even though the closure has no parameters defined. This is what I want, if possible.

Comment: I think I get you now. Try instead of `call_user_func_array($this->groupHandler)` to do `($this->groupHandler)())` hopefully this will invoke the closure as it's been bound

Comment: Based on the idea of @apokryfos I implemented a solution that allows me to make use of your solution too. I accepted his answer, since it gave me the sparkling idea, but I wanted to thank you again for your effort and for a correct solution. You can see the implementation in the big update of my question, if you wish. Good luck!

Comment: @aendeerei - i was trying to remember the `bind` way but I almost never use it, so...  But anyway, it's all good as long as you got it sorted out.  Thanks for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

In an abstract sense you can achieve this using the [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php) function of a closure:

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$routeHandler = Closure::bind(function() {
    $this->addRoute('GET', '/group', function() {
       echo 'Hello from route /test/group';
   });
}, $routes);

$routes->addGroup('/test', $routeHandler);
```

This is useful when you want to pass this closure around but want to maintain scope.

Comment: Thank you, apokryfos for your answer! Let me think about it. I also made an edit to my question (named "Edit").

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment that you wrote bellow, at the answer from Phoenix. I was very busy with testing and debuging and reading... :-) Let me test your idea now. Thanks for it!

Comment: Nope, your second idea didn't work. BUUUTTT, in the mean time, I found out - and implemented - your initial solution. It is one that allows me not only to resolve my problem in my asked way, but, optionally, in two other ways as well!! Including the very correct form proposed by Phoenix. Thank you very much! :-)) I will edit my question in the next minutes with the implemented solution based on your idea. Have a nice night!

Comment: I feel like you should answer your initial question with the solution and accept that as the answer. It might help others more easily if a complete working solution is marked as accepted.

Comment: Hi. This is a good proposal, but I didn't want to take the credit for the solution that you correctly provided. It wouldn't have been fair ;-) But, if you have nothing against it, I will write an answer and "accept" it as well, giving the credits to your solution. And I owe you one then :-)